# d3.voronoi with svg panning and zooming, pan idenifitely

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

At this moment I generate d3 voronoi points, run through relaxations, render polygons and apply svg-pan-zoom to the whole thing. I want to create an indefinite panning for this voronoi map. It will be used as a 2D map that represents a sphere (a world).

I want to create this illusion by wrapping the voronoi diagram both horizontally and vertically. I know that creating an actual 3D sphere made of random voronoi cells would be an option but I'm looking for something simpler right now.

How would you approach such a problem? Below are some screenshots to better represent what I am asking.

[image]

Instead of cutting it when panning too far I would love to be able to just force the right side of the voronoi diagram to be somehow seamlessly glued to the left side. Kinda like in old Pacman games.

I am looking for some clues, mathematical rules that could help or some tricks to d3/d3.voronoi/svg-pan-zoom.

Comment: 1. Tiles that are "on the border" will always be water tiles so there is no need for actual data-checking. It could be hacky as long as it would appear seamless.

Comment: Why not modify the voronoi code to treat wrap-around coordinates as neighbours.  Or alternatively, add a border around all four edges of your original rectangle and mirror the points across from the opposite sides. Run the voronoi algorithm.  Then if you trim the SVG back to the original size, it should be seamless.

Comment: These are some great tips, thank you. Do you have some mathematical/programmatical clues for making those points on edges behave like neighbours?

Comment: It will depend on which algorithm you are using. But you will need to remember that for every point (x,y) in you set, there eight other clones of it on the neighbouring tiles (x-w,y-h), (x,y-h), (x+w,y-h), (x-w,y), (x+w,y), (x-w,y+h), (x,y+h), (x+w,y+h),